# Groovy:unexpected token when using Grails and Spring security core plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I require to add Spring Security core to Grails.
I have added the spring core security plugin to a grails 2.3.8 app,
using: BuildConfig.groovy
plugins {
...
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
...

then
s2-quickstart sim GUser GRole

The file GUserGRole.groovy contains the following errors:

Groovy:unexpected token: validator @ line 82, column 9.
Multiple markers at this line
    - Groovy:expecting EOF, found 'if' @ line 83, 
     column 4.
    - Groovy:unexpected token: if @ line 83, 
     column 4.

which corresponds to the following code:

```
static constraints = {
    GRole validator: { GRole r, GUserGRole ur ->
        if (ur.GUser == null) return
        boolean existing = false
        GUserGRole.withNewSession {
            existing = GUserGRole.exists(ur.GUser.id, r.id)
        }
        if (existing) {
            return 'userRole.exists'
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be resolved? 
How can I cleanly add Spring Security core to Grails??

Comment: This code doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: The code shown is created automatically when I run quickstart after installing the security plugin.

Comment: Same issue with Grails 2.4.4 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC3/RC4 with IDEA 14.

Answer (score 1):

s2quick-start uses GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyNameRepresentation to generate the instance fields for your domain classes. Use a name that will generate a suitable field name otherwise the field name and the class name are the same.

```
 //This is fine - generates 'user'
 GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyNameRepresentation("User") 

 //This is fine - generates 'myUser'
 GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyNameRepresentation("MyUser")

 //Not fine. Generates 'GRole' which is same as your class name
 GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyNameRepresentation("GRole")
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the `GRole validator`.  The thing before `validator` there should be the name of the property that is being constrained, not the type.  If the property is called `gRole` then the code should be `gRole validator`.  Is the property really called `GRole`?  That might be problematic if it is.

Comment: Following installing the spring security plugin, I ran quickstart to initialise the plugin. GRole, along with GUser was created as a property name within GUserGRole. I was under the impression that with Grails 2, it was very straightforward to install the spring security core plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the discussion here [Groovy: Unexpected token ":"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820367/groovy-unexpected-token)?

Since the code is auto generated you should manually correct the names of your class variables and change it as "GRole GRole" to "GRole gRole".