# Groovy: Unexpected token ":"

Tags: groovy

I have this auto generated lines of codes:

```
EPRole validator: { EPRole r, EPUserEPRole ur ->
            if (ur.EPUser == null) return
            boolean existing = false
            EPUserEPRole.withNewSession {
                existing = EPUserEPRole.exists(ur.EPUser.id, r.id)
            }
            if (existing) {
                return 'userRole.exists'
            }
        }
```

When I try to compile the code I get `82: unexpected token: validator @ line 82, column 10.`

I am new in groovy so any help is appreciated.

Comment: should be epRole? EPRole would be the class

Comment: Ah, now I get it. The whole class is auto generated and you are right that the error depend on capital and lower cases. How can I accept your answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your properties with the proper type and name to the class. First letter uppercase is for classes (or types in general).  So there should be in your `EPUserEPRole` a property like this:

```
EPRole epRole
```

Then add the validator for `epRole`.  Pay attention to the case.

Above code would confuse the groovy parser into defining a property `validator` of type `EPRole` followed by a `:`, hence the error (or else it would try to call the method EPRole with the map, depending on context).